# Stuck on using "for if..."

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop

I have 3 checkboxes under 1 PK. Following is the code for check boxes.

**JSP**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="500K" name="500K" value="Y" checked="checked"/>500K</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="1000K" name="1000K" value="Y" checked="checked"/>1000K</label></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="2000K" name="2000K" value="Y" checked="checked"/>2000K</label></span>
```

Given that all three boxes are selected, I want the data to be like;

```
**PK         VALUE**    
1            500k   

1            1000k   

1            2000k   

2            500k

2            1000k

2            2000k
3...
```

Given that the value for Checkboxe is Y, I want it to become 500K, 1000k, 2000k for each Y and inserted into value column.
So for every pk, it should have 3 values; 500k, 1000k, 2000k in DB.

I know I should do something with

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/..."})
public String encodeRegSaveDo(HttpServletResponse response,
                          HttpServletRequest request,
                          ModelMap model,
                          Condition condition,
                          @RequestParam Map<String, Object> maps,
                          @ModelAttribute Encode encode) throws Exception  {        
  for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
  EncodeRepository.saveRegVq(encode);
```

The edit should be occurred in Controller page.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you be explain little bit more.Where you exactly want to iterate?

Comment: I want to iterate in Controller. And data should be looked like that in DB.

Comment: You can done it using java collection class..better you can have a look at Map concept or Array list for storing the data in a specific way such you prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chek box must have diffrent value but same name

```
<input type="checkbox" id="500K" name="Y" value="500K" checked="checked"/>500K</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="1000K" name="Y" value="1000K" checked="checked"/>1000K</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="2000K" name="Y" value="2000K" checked="checked"/>2000K</label>



 <% 
    String[] SelectedValues = request.getParameterValues("Y");
    System.out.println("checked boxes:");

   for (int i = 0; i < SelectedValues.length; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println("  " + SelectedValues[i]);
        // EncodeRepository.saveRegVq(encode); try like this
    }
  %>
```